# jQuery Form Validation not showing error upon failure

Tags: javascript, jquery

Note: this is a jQuery coding exercise so I am not allowed to use plugins or other modules.

I made a simple, typical form and want to check to make sure that the form fields are entered and not left blank. If they are, the appropriate message appears showing an error. I have not succeeded in this so far.

After this I will add a function to make sure a valid email is entered.

My form:

```
<form id="myForm">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email">
          <span class="error">Email not entered</span><br />
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pword" name="pword">
          <span class="error">Password not entered</span><br />
          <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" name="fname">
          <span class="error">First Name not entered</span><br />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" name="lname">
          <span class="error">Last Name not entered</span><br />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // field mapping
    var form_fields = {
        'email' : 'email',
        'pword' : 'password',
        'fname' : 'first name',
        'lname' : 'last name'
    };

    // make sure form fields were entered
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        for (var field in form_fields) {
            if (!$('#' + field).val()) {
                $('#' + field + ' span').addClass('.error_show');
            }
        }

    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.error {
    display: none;
}

.error_show {
    display: inline-block;
    color: red;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything works fine except the way you are selecting you subsequent `span` of the `element` plus the way you are adding the `error class`. You can use <kbd>**[.next](https://api.jquery.com/next/)**</kbd> to find the next `element` of the `input` validated and then I would like to mention the below changes to be done and here is the **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/032nv28t/)**

```
for (var field in form_fields) {
   if (!$('#' + field).val()) {
        $('#' + field).next('.error').addClass('error_show'); //get the next element with class .error
   }
}
```

> The way you were adding class was `.addClass('.error_show');` and here
>   `.` should not be given while adding class since its not a selector
>   and is a classname.

---

**UPDATE**

Your `selector` will work if `span` was `child` of `'#'+field` and since it was `sibling` it wasn't able to find the particular `span` with the way you were using it.. Alternatively you could have used `#' + field +' ~ span'` or `#' + field +' + span'`. **[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/032nv28t/1/)**. Know more about different selectors **[here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

Comment: Thanks! I will use your answer. On a side note do you know why `$('#' + field + ' span')` was not working?